# jQuery .fadeTo() method with .click()

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeto

I am using .fadeToggle() to fade in & out a div element. Here is its HTML and script

```
<div id="image2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" /> </div>
<div class="divButton2"><br/> Button 3!</div>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divButton2').click(function(){
        $('div#image2').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Now I am using .fadeTo() method with semi-transparent opacity

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divButton2').click(function(){
        $('#image2').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
    }); 
});
```

and once I click a button it is halfway faded out now I would like to click again so it fades back in completely. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divButton2').click(function(){
     if($('#image2').css('opacity') == 1){
       $('#image2').fadeTo('slow', 0.2);
     }else{
       $('#image2').fadeTo('slow', 1);
     }  
    }); 
});
```

or you can use .animate()

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.divButton2').on('click',function(){
         if($('#image2').css('opacity') == 1){
           $('#image2').animate({'opacity': 0.2}, 1000);
         }else{
           $('#image2').animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
         }  
        }); 
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ye8j8xfy/1/)

Comment: Sorry all is fine it was browser's  glitch. Thank you again

Comment: I have decreased its opacity to 0.2 in both 'if' and 'else' statement however, for some reasons it is not fading back in ...

Comment: @DurdonaAbdusamikovna check it again it will work whatever your opacity is .. and check that you don't have any duplicated ID   #image2

Comment: it is not fading back in let me try in jsfiddle

Comment: @DurdonaAbdusamikovna  you are right.. check my updated answer